# Android Emulators on windows

Tags: android-emulator

I am using android studio 2.3 with window 8.1 my emulator  appear for some seconds and after that disppear also genymotion  doesn't work appear for long duration with white screen.

Answer (score 0):

To help us repro the issue can you add the following information: https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs.html#emulator-bugs

Once you have the info, file a bug here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Android%20Emulator%20Bug